# In SpeechRecognition how can I get a print out of the current set energy threshold if set it by adjust_for_ambient_noise

Tags: python, speech-recognition

In Speech Recognition how can I get a print out of the current set energy threshold if set it by adjust_for_ambient_noise.
I would like to run a few test and record the energy threshold automatically by using

```
r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)
```

much thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
print(r.energy_threshold)
```

> Adjusts the energy threshold dynamically using audio from `source`
> (an `AudioSource` instance) to account for ambient noise.
>
> Intended to calibrate the energy threshold with the ambient energy
> level. Should be used on periods of audio without speech - will stop
> early if any speech is detected.
>
> The `duration` parameter is the maximum number of seconds that it
> will dynamically adjust the threshold for before returning.